# Generating ID from starting event

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that has customer ID and an event type. Every time I have EVENT1 I would like to increment a counter, however if the event is EVENT2 or EVENT3 then the counter should inherit the previous value. Ultimately this will give me a unique identifier, based on EVENT1 which is the starting action.

This would be easy in Excel, but I am struggling to create SQL which can replicate this.

Thanks in advance!

Table data:

```
Customer ID | Event
001         | EVENT1
001         | EVENT1
001         | EVENT1
001         | EVENT2
001         | EVENT3
001         | EVENT1
001         | EVENT1
001         | EVENT2
```

Desired output:

```
Customer ID | Event  | UniqueID
001         | EVENT1 | 1
001         | EVENT1 | 2
001         | EVENT1 | 3
001         | EVENT2 | 3
001         | EVENT3 | 3
001         | EVENT1 | 4
001         | EVENT1 | 5
001         | EVENT2 | 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding of SQL tables, because you are assuming that your rows are in some sort of order.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets unless a column explicitly provides the ordering.

Let me assume that you have such an column, say `id` or a date/time column.  You can do what you want using an analytic function:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when event = 'EVENT1' then 1 else 0 end) over
           (partition by customer_id order by id) as event1Id
from t;
```

Also note my reluctance to call something "UniqueId" when it clearly is not unique.

Comment: Thanks. As you say, the table is ordered, I omitted to try and keep the question simple, which obviously backfired!